# Can we have a table backup scheduled

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to take a backup of a table in my database for every 2hrs is it possible?

I have a backup table in my database which holds the values from a different table

I wanted to know whether I can schedule this backup for every two hours

I dont need a full database back up i need just a table

Comment: possible duplicate of [table level backup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680552/table-level-backup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the table into its own filegroup and backup just that filegroup.  [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179401%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) describes how to back up a single file or filegroup.

Answer (score 0):

You can backup the whole database using the method outlined in this post:
[how to schedule backup in sql server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180007/how-to-schedule-backup-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: I dont need a full database backup i need just a table backup